# Numpy Value Error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,99) (100,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gaussian

I am attemping to define y equal to (x × 0.15) + N where N is a 100 element 1D array of random values chosen from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 0.5 but I keep getting the error code : **ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,99) (100,)** . Any tips on how I can revise my code to make it work would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
N = np.random.normal (0, 0.5,size=(100))
y = (np.dot([x],0.15)) + N
```

Comment: What is `x`?  and what is the intended shape of `y`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you included the `x` array in your example above. Python is complaining that `(np.dot([x],0.15))` has dimensions `np.shape(1,99)`, which means that `x` has the same shape. You could `x.flatten()` to make it `np.shape(99)`, but then you still have the problem that `x` has 99 elements, and `N` has 100, and python does not know how to add two arrays of dissimilar length.

Assuming this is somehow wrong, and that `x` should have had 100 elements, you could just do

```
x = np.arange(100) # Example x-array, use your own in stead
N = np.random.normal(0, 0.5,size=x.shape)
y = x*0.15 + N
```

since all `(np.dot([x],0.15))` does in this case is to multiply each element of `x` with 0.15, which much simpler written as the above.

Comment: You could also use the shape of x as the size of the random array. `np.random.normal (0, 0.5,size=x.shape)`

Comment: Good point, added that to the suggestion.